# PHP OO overwrite const through extending

Tags: php, class, oop, constants, extends

I got an strange thing:

```
<?php
    class LW_Base{
        const MULTIPLE = 'LW_Base';

        public static function name(){
            return strtolower(static::MULTIPLE);
        }
    }

    class LW_Extend extends LW_Base{
        const MULTITPLE = 'LW_Extend';
    }

    $t = new LW_Extend();

    echo $t::name().'==LW_Extend';
?>
```

this is an really reduced code-snipped of an little (350 Lines - NCLOC) PHP-Project. 
The Output should be "lw_extend==LW_Extend", but it acutally is "lw_base==LW_Extend".

I swear: in an other, bigger Project (1155 Lines - NCLOC), more complex (Namespaces, Class-Hirarchys, a lot of functions, ...) this is working.

The Question: What do I do wrong / unstable? If something works once, it has to work twice.

Please: I do really need an info. I'am searching for a week. I think the solution has to be simple, because it works on another project (I actually can't paste infos about that other project, sorry)

Regards, and thanks for every posting,
  Oli

Comment: `MULTITPLE != MULTIPLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling Mistake for const declaration for 2 classes,

```
const MULTIPLE = 'LW_Base';

const MULTITPLE = 'LW_Extend';
```

You have to call the constant in same class as **self**

```
    class LW_Base{
        const MULTIPLE = 'LW_Base';

        public static function name(){
            return strtolower(self::MULTIPLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: OH NOOOOOOOOOOOOO :) THANKS :) Haha... note: befor i wrote here, i did consult two other frinds of mine, also good PHP Developers ^^ THANKS again :) It works